# R: Inferring a Common Merge Key

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, join, merge

I am trying to webscrape a site to get addresses for a set of names (part A) along with the longitude and latitudes (part B). I don't know how to do this all together, so I did this in two parts:

```
# part A
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)

# Define function to scrape 1 page
get_info <- function(page_n) {
  cat("Scraping page ", page_n, "\n")
  page <- paste0("https://www.mywebsite/",
    page_n, "?extension") %>% read_html
  tibble(title = page %>%
           html_elements(".title a") %>%
           html_text2(),
         adress = page %>%  
           html_elements(".marker") %>% 
           html_text2(),
         page = page_n)
}

# Apply function to pages 1:10
df_1 <- map_dfr(1:10, get_info)

# Check dimensions
dim(df_1)
[1] 90
```

Here is part B:

```
# Recognize pattern in websites
part1 = "https://www.mywebsite/"
part2 = c(0:55)
part3 = "extension"
temp = data.frame(part1, part2, part3)

# Create list of websites
temp$all_websites = paste0(temp$part1, temp$part2, temp$part3)
# Scrape
df_2 <- list()
for (i in 1:10)
{tryCatch({
    url_i <-temp$all_websites[i]
    page_i <-read_html(url_i)
    b_i = page_i %>% html_nodes("head")
    listanswer_i <- b_i %>% html_text() %>% strsplit("\\n")
    df_2[[i]] <- listanswer_i
    print(listanswer_i)
}, error = function(e){})
}

# Extract long/lat from results

lat_long = grep("LatLng", unlist(df_2[]), value = TRUE)
df_2 = data.frame(str_match(lat_long, "LatLng(\\s*(.*?)\\s*);"))
df_2 = df_2 %>% filter(X1 != "LatLngBounds();")

> dim(df_2)
[1] 86  3
```

We can see that `df_1` and `df_2` have a different number of rows - but also, there is no common **merge key** between `df_1` and `df_2`. How can I re-write my code in such a way that I can create a **merge key** between `df_1` and `df_2` such that I can merge the common records between these files together?

Comment: Constraints/FKs/PKs need not be declared, known or exist to query. Keys are used by ORMs for shorthands for joins, but they needn't be declared or declarable. What matters is the condition for membership in base tables & the condition for membership in a result table. The ORM shorthand just uses equality of FK & PK. You are talking about "natural join" which is a df merge default.

Comment: @  philipxy: thank you so much for your comment! This is the first time I heard of a "natural join"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure multiple requests to the same URIs are needed. There are some lat long values not listed either on the results pages or on the result specific linked webpage e.g.Toronto Beaches Dentist from current page 2 results has no lat long shown on either page 2 or the website specific page. In these cases, you may choose to fill the blanks using another service which returns lat long based on an address.

You can re-write your function and alter your regex patterns to produce 2 dataframes which can be joined and the resultant dataframe returned. With the appropriate regex changes, as given below, you can use the address column to join the 2 dataframes. I dislike a key which is an address but it does appear to be internally consistent across the result page. I have used a left join to return all rows from the dentist listings i.e. the practice business names.

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

urls <- sprintf("https://www.dentistsearch.ca/search-doctor/%i?category=0&services=0&province=55&city=&k=", 1:10)
pages <- lapply(urls, read_html)

get_dentist_info <- function(page) {
  
  page_text <- page %>% html_text()
  
  address_keys <- page_text %>%
    str_match_all('marker_\\d+\\.set\\("content", "(.*?)"\\);') %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    .[, 2]
  
  lat_long <- page_text %>%
    str_match_all("LatLng\\((.*)\\);(?![\\s\\S]+myOptions)") %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    .[, 2]
  lat_lon <- tibble(address = address_keys, lat_long = lat_long) %>%
    separate(lat_long, into = c("lat", "long"), sep = ", ") %>%
    mutate(lat = as.numeric(lat), long = as.numeric(long))

  practice_info <- tibble(
    title = page %>% html_elements(".title > a") %>% html_text(trim = T),
    address = page %>% html_elements(".marker") %>% html_text()
  )

  dentist_info <- left_join(practice_info, lat_lon, by = "address")
  return(dentist_info)
}

all_dentist_info <- map_dfr(pages, get_dentist_info)
```

Comment: @ QHarr: wow, wow, wow! this is such an amazing answer! thank you so much! I will have to spend some time studying your answer to learn more about the functions and logic you decided to implement in this answer! The one immediate question I had was : how does your code ensure that the "correct" longitude/latitude is assigned to each name/address?  At the end of the code, you are using a LEFT JOIN on "address" - this means that somehow you were able to find an "address" for both "name" and "longitude/latitude" and then use "address" as a JOIN KEY? My weekend will be spent studying your code! :)

Comment: In the page source html there are JavaScript "blocks" which list in order the latlon and associated address within the re-used `var myLatlng` and associated marker e.g. marker0, 1 .....

Comment: As an example, results page 1 page source (Ctrl+U) copied into regex tool and showing the 2 regexes before applying the extra \ escape required in R `https://regex101.com/r/vjEwgE/1` and `https://regex101.com/r/Ws5r6I/1` The boxes on the right explain the regexes.